# Save data from text file to SQL database

Tags: ruby

I have some data in a text file in the following format:

```
Cat 3 24 2 2 4 6 4 7 6 0 0
Dog 18 0 8 2 42 6 6 4 5 8 0 
Mouse 8 1 2 2 4 6 4 7 6 0 0
Rabbit 8 10 8 26 46 2 6 7 6 10 0
```

I would like to write a Ruby script which can take this data and store it in SQLite database where the table's columns will be : Name, Value1, Value2, Value3,...., Value11. And the rows are each piece of data on every line of the file, so the first row of the table will be: Cat, 3, 24, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4, 7, 6, 0, 0.

I have my class for Data set up as follows:

```
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'


DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")

class Data
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :value1, Integer
  property :value2, Integer
  property :value3, Integer
  property :value4, Integer
  property :value5, Integer
  property :value6, Integer
  property :value7, Integer
  property :value8, Integer
  property :value9, Integer
  property :value10, Integer
  property :value11, Integer
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

In my app.rb I'm trying to write down the logic that can parse this data and create and write it to the database. I'm also using Sinatra for this. How do I go about doing that?

EDIT: Updated app.rb file

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'slim'
require 'sass'
require './Names'
require 'rubygems'
require 'data_mapper'

get '/' do

  File.readlines("data.txt").each do |line|
    name, *values = line.split
    params = {:name => name}
    values.each_with_index do |value, i|
      params[:"value#{i+1}"] = value
    end
    my_data = Names.new params #class renamed to Names
    my_data.save
  end

end
```

When I do this I get a NoMethodError - undefined method `validators' for Names:Class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary, or especially desirable, that you use "edit" or "update" tags. Instead incorporate the change as if you'd put it there initially so the content makes sense and flows. We can see what changed if we're interested.

Answer (score 1):

This is a start :

```
File.readlines('data.txt').each_with_index do |line, i|
  name, *values = line.split
  values.map!{|v| v.to_i}
  puts i
  puts name
  puts values.inspect
end
```

You get the index, the name and the values for each row.

It returns :

```
0
Cat
[3, 24, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4, 7, 6, 0, 0]

1
Dog
[18, 0, 8, 2, 42, 6, 6, 4, 5, 8, 0]

2
Mouse
[8, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4, 7, 6, 0, 0]

3
Rabbit
[8, 10, 8, 26, 46, 2, 6, 7, 6, 10, 0]
```

Now that you have the desired variables, you can write them into your database.
To do so, you can create a params Hash with the expected attributes for your Data :

```
File.readlines('data.txt').each do |line|
  name, *values = line.split
  params = {:name => name}
  values.each_with_index do |value, i|
    params[:"value#{i+1}"] = value
  end
  my_data = MyData.new params
  my_data.save
end

puts MyData.count # => 4
```

**NOTE**: Do not call your class Data, it is already defined in Ruby and you will get weird errors.

## Stand-alone Example

Everything put together :

```
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'

# Initialize Database

DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")

class MyData
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :value1, Integer
  property :value2, Integer
  property :value3, Integer
  property :value4, Integer
  property :value5, Integer
  property :value6, Integer
  property :value7, Integer
  property :value8, Integer
  property :value9, Integer
  property :value10, Integer
  property :value11, Integer
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!

# Parse file and save data in DB

File.foreach('data.txt') do |line|
  name, *values = line.split
  params = { name: name }
  values.each_with_index do |value, i|
    params[:"value#{i + 1}"] = value
  end
  MyData.create params
end

puts MyData.count # => 4, then 8, then 12, ...
```

Comment: Thank you, it was what I was looking for. How exactly is it storing it? If I put it in a def block, will it return it as a hash or something else?

Comment: See update. You can create your MyData objects directly inside the loop.

Comment: I tried that along with the code I edited into my post, but the database is created but not populated for some reason. Its using Sinatra in case it helps.

Comment: Instead of using `readlines`, which slurps the content and can cause scalability problems, use `foreach`. It's extremely fast and will work with `with_index` if you need the line number, though `$.`, AKA `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` will do the same. See the [English](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/English/rdoc/English.html) module.

Comment: @theTinMan I tried foreach instead of readlines, and am still getting a  NoMethodError - undefined method `validators' for Names:Class. error .

Comment: Rename `class Data` to `class Names`.